# Replacing the dots for a list of abbreviations?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I'm trying to remove the dots of a list of abbreviations so that they will not confuse the sentence tokenizer. This is should be very straightforward. Don't know why my code is not working.

Below please find my code:

```
abbrevs = [
    "No.", "U.S.", "Mses.", "B.S.", "B.A.", "D.C.", "B.Tech.", "Pte.", "Mr.", "O.E.M.",
    "I.R.S", "sq.", "Reg.", "S-K."
]



def replace_abbrev(abbrs, text):
    re_abbrs = [r"\b" + re.escape(a) + r"\b" for a in abbrs]

    abbr_no_dot = [a.replace(".", "") for a in abbrs]

    pattern_zip = zip(re_abbrs, abbr_no_dot)

    for p in pattern_zip:
        text = re.sub(p[0], p[1], text)

    return text

text = "Test No. U.S. Mses. B.S. Test"

text = replace_abbrev(abbrevs, text)

print(text)
```

Here is the result. Nothing happened. What was wrong? Thanks.

```
 Test No. U.S. Mses. B.S. Test
```

Comment: What is the `re_abbrs = [r"\b" + re.escape(a) + r"\b" for a in abbrs]` line for? Because removing it makes it work for this test case!

Comment: I want to match the whole word, so I add word boundaries.

Comment: You're just trying to rid all periods?

Comment: Yes, that's I'm trying to do.

Comment: remove the '\b' after re.escape(a)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
re_abbrs = [r"\b" + re.escape(a)  for a in abbrs]
```

You need to use this.There is no `\b` after `.` .This gives the correct output.

`Test No US Mses BS Test`

Comment: Thank you very much. I already took me more than one hour trying to figure out.

Comment: Removing the second r"\b" will match patterns like U.S.A. I changed it to r"\b" + re.escape(a) + r"(?=\s+)" . Very happy with the results. Thank you for pointing this out.

Comment: @VictorWang you might want to use `r"\b" + re.escape(a) + r"(?=(?:\s+|$))"` in case the last word ends with `.`

Answer (score 1):

You could use [map](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) and [operator.methodcaller](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.methodcaller) no need for re even though it's a great library.

```
from operator import methodcaller

' '.join(map(methodcaller('replace', '.', ''), abbrevs))
#No US Mses BS BA DC BTech Pte Mr OEM IRS sq Reg S-K
```